# chrono convert DateTime<Utc> to NaiveDate

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

After a while of fiddling, I decided to ask the question here, because - others shallst not waste as much fiddling time as I have.

So, how to convert a `DateTime<Utc>` into a `NaiveDate` with Rusts `chrono` crate?

Here the "fill in the blanks" kind of test code:

```
#[test]
  fn test_utc_now_to_naive_date() {
    let utc_now = Utc::now();
    let now: NaiveDate = ???? // how?
  }
```

I attribute the fact, that in most languages, time and date function libraries are over- designed monsters to the PTSD people suffered from the Y2K bug...

We have traits like `Datelike` and should that not help converting one date-like thing into another? Well - I could not find the solution...

Comment: This method: https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.date_naive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods [`DateTime.naive_utc`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.naive_utc) and [`NaiveDateTime.date`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html#method.date) are well documented:

```rust
let now: NaiveDate = utc_now.naive_utc().date();
```

Or the even simpler version from [Jonas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75591625/chrono-convert-datetimeutc-to-naivedate/75591691?noredirect=1#comment133363028_75591625), using [`DateTime.date_naive`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.date_naive):

```rust
let now = utc_now.date_naive();
```

Comment: I tried to intellisense my way to the solution. So ".into_ hmm... nothing as DateLike ...nope, ... from_datelike ... now way... etc ad nauseum"

Comment: Well reading the documentation is an essential programming skill imho.

Comment: Also shows that intellisense isn't a great tool to discover parts of an API, nor is it designed to be one.

Comment: Maybe your gripe is with `chrono` and it's interface, in that case you're free to submit a PR, use any other time library of your choosing or provide your own.